# Quorum 7nodes example unable to attach to geth node 1,2,4,5,6,7 but node 3 is working

Tags: go-ethereum, blockchain, private-blockchain, metamask, quorum

Quorum 7nodes example all of sudden gave fatal error unable to attach to remote geth.
Problem: can't attach to geth node 
Every time I import metamask account to geth node (using personal.importRawKey("private key", "password")) to use that account to interact with Dapp using metamask. when i restart the machine and try to open geth node I am unable to access that particular geth node(let say node 1) but all other nodes work fine.

PFA screenshot 
[image]

Comment: Are you running this using Vagrant + VirtualBox? If so, one thing would be to check the available memory in your virtual environment. Do the IPC endpoints actually exist under the `qdata/dd<x>/` directories?

Comment: yes I am using vagrant and VirtualBox , and i can see a file names geth.ipc under the qdata/dd<x> folder.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a memory issue, but you should look into the logs available in qdata/logs folder.

Latest quorum-examples updates memory requirement to 6GB, tho the minimum is 4GB for all 7nodes to run simultaneously.

Comment: This problem occurred  after I imported metamask account to Quorum geth node/s (using personal.importRawKey) . after restart only those node stopped working in which i  imported account.

Comment: This is odd, probably best to join our Slack and debug in real time with the devs or maybe open an issue on github

Answer (score 0):

The problem is dd1/geth.ipc not found, where is your ethereum-get folder ?

You have to linked the geth.ipc to quorum first.Or you can do it by manually.

Use geth private network it will create two folders geth and keystore.You need to create encode code for peer also.

you can use this geth and keystore and linked them with Quorum. Encode of peers are shared globally in quorum. You can see /Users/yudiz/Documents/quorum-examples/examples/7nodes/qdata/dd1/permissioned-nodes.json

Permissioned-nodes.json

```
 [
  "enode://ac6b1096ca56b9f6d004b779ae3728bf83f8e22453404cc3cef16a3d9b96608bc67c4b30db88e0a5a6c6390213f7acbe1153ff6d23ce57380104288ae19373ef@127.0.0.1:21000?discport=0&raftport=50401",
  "enode://0ba6b9f606a43a95edc6247cdb1c1e105145817be7bcafd6b2c0ba15d58145f0dc1a194f70ba73cd6f4cdd6864edc7687f311254c7555cc32e4d45aeb1b80416@127.0.0.1:21001?discport=0&raftport=50402",
  "enode://579f786d4e2830bbcc02815a27e8a9bacccc9605df4dc6f20bcc1a6eb391e7225fff7cb83e5b4ecd1f3a94d8b733803f2f66b7e871961e7b029e22c155c3a778@127.0.0.1:21002?discport=0&raftport=50403",
  "enode://3d9ca5956b38557aba991e31cf510d4df641dce9cc26bfeb7de082f0c07abb6ede3a58410c8f249dabeecee4ad3979929ac4c7c496ad20b8cfdd061b7401b4f5@127.0.0.1:21003?discport=0&raftport=50404",
  "enode://3701f007bfa4cb26512d7df18e6bbd202e8484a6e11d387af6e482b525fa25542d46ff9c99db87bd419b980c24a086117a397f6d8f88e74351b41693880ea0cb@127.0.0.1:21004?discport=0&raftport=50405",
  "enode://eacaa74c4b0e7a9e12d2fe5fee6595eda841d6d992c35dbbcc50fcee4aa86dfbbdeff7dc7e72c2305d5a62257f82737a8cffc80474c15c611c037f52db1a3a7b@127.0.0.1:21005?discport=0&raftport=50406",
  "enode://239c1f044a2b03b6c4713109af036b775c5418fe4ca63b04b1ce00124af00ddab7cc088fc46020cdc783b6207efe624551be4c06a994993d8d70f684688fb7cf@127.0.0.1:21006?discport=0&raftport=50407"
]
```

let me know if you found any problem again

Comment: Please check my reply there let me know if your code doesn't run